# Combining two dictionaries into one

Tags: python

I have the following Python code I am trying to execute but the interpreter is returning prematurely. I believe it is because I am trying to combine two dictionaries as if they were lists:

```
both = {}
one = {"A" : 0}
two = {"B" : 0}
both = one + two    // Returns prematurely here
```

How can I combine two dictionaries into one?

Answer (score 0):

```
both = {}
one = {"A" : 0}
two = {"B" : 0}
both.update(one)
both.update(two)
print one
print both
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried `one.update(two)`? It will give you the desired combined dict. But you need to be careful as keys in both are overwritten.